# Android application can not load once a new class is introduced

Tags: android

Hello there am crawling into this android world slowly and following the android bootcamp exercise 2012 edition. I am able to test my application on the AVm with just one layout and one class however on introducing the second class, second layout and coding the button, the application does not open and the log cat error looks like this

```
06-18 17:22:29.461: D/AndroidRuntime(542): Shutting down VM
06-18 17:22:29.461: W/dalvikvm(542): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.example.helloworld.Main.onCreate(Main.java:24)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
06-18 17:22:29.471: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  ... 11 more
```

***this is the main.java***

```
public class Main extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Recipe.class));
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                     .commit();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

     }

     /**
       * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
      */

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {}

        @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
          }
      }
    }
```

***this is the new class***

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Recipe extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

    }

}
```

this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.helloworld.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Recipe"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*activity_main*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.Main"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.Main$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/mduduzi_games"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/anim4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does your `activity_main` XML layout look like?

Comment: I have uploaded the activity_main and the fragment_main, please review @Tanis.7x

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace, there is a `NullPointerException` on line 24 of Main.java:

```
at com.example.helloworld.Main.onCreate(Main.java:24)
```

This is your problem:

```
 Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
 //b is null, so the next line throws a NullPointerException:
 b.setOnClickListener(...
```

b is null, meaning there is no Button with the id "btnPlay" in `activity_main.xml`

Check to make sure you have something like this in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

### EDIT:

You are calling `findViewById` from your `Activity`, which is searching amongst the `Views` of your `Activity` defined by `activity_main.xml`. Since you have defined your Button in your `Fragment` layout, you must get a reference to the Button from within your `Fragment` code. Remove the `Button` code from your `Activity` class, and stick it into your `Fragment`:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    public PlaceholderFragment() {}

    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
         //find your Button view in rootView
         Button b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Recipe.class));
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
         });
        return rootView;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Sam this is already in the fragment_main, I have uploaded both of them please have a look

Comment: @MrRobbes you should move your button code to your Fragment - see the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you are on the right path, you need to change a line slightly in your manifest. Try:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.helloworld.Recipe"></activity>
```

Instead of

```
<activity android:name="Recipe"></activity>
```

EDIT: Actually, this doesn't seem to be the source of your *current* problem, but will be a source of a *future* problem once your current `NullPointerException` is fixed. As stated in other answers, it looks to deal with the button you set to navigate to your new Activity.

Comment: That's an issue too, but not the issue he's seeing. And, I believe he could just use <activity android:name=".Recipe" />

Comment: I actually realized that right before you commented, and edited my post. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Hi @kevinrmannix I have done as recommended, unfortunately it is still crushing, as for the null pointer, the button is already in fragment_main, this version of eclipse is giving both fragment_main and activity_main! I am using an adt bundle I downloaded over a week ago could this be an issue?

Comment: I don't believe so. Look at Tanis.7x's answer, he seems to have delved into the issue appropriately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `btnPlay` is defined in your Fragment's layout, but you are trying to find it in your Activity before the Fragment is added to the Activity.

When you call `findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);`, the only thing that has been added to your Activity's layout is `activity_main`, which only contains a FrameLayout. The Fragment containing `btnPlay` doesn't exist until you call

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
    .commit();
```

One solution would be to move the above three lines to before `Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);`.

However, it is generally a bad practice to reference Views defined in a Fragment from an Activity, because it is a very poor separation of concerns. Your Fragment should handle of the user interaction with Views belonging to that Fragment, and your Activity should only be concerned with Views defined in the Activity's layout.